# How to change post login route in rydurham/sentinel in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I am using laravel 4.2 and for authentication and user group management i am using [sentinel](https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel)

In this package by default after login it goes to `home` route. I want to take to my custom route all the time. How can i do that? I searched in controllers but they all shows route to some config.

Can anybody help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  `config/packages/rydurham/sentinel/config.php`

On line 71 change

```
'post_login'    => 'home',
```

to

```
'post_login'    => 'your_desired_route',
```

Comment: thank you. it the solution i was searching for. Now can i change other config there too?